# Recursive function that takes in a list and an integer and returns the integer in the list in order

Tags: python, recursion

So let's say I this function:

```
squeeze([1,4,7,9], 8)
squeeze([1,4,7,9], 0)
```

I would want the function to return a new list containing:

```
[1,4,7,8,9]
[0,1,4,7,9]
```

I want to make this function using recursion, but I'm having trouble

```
def squeeze(x:list, num:int):
    if len(x) == 1:
        if num < x[0]:
            return [num] + x #if the integer is less than the 1st value, put it in the front
        elif x[0] < num < x[2]: 
            return [x[0]] + [num] + [x[2]] #put it in the list
         #insert this number into the correct spot
    else: 
        return squeeze(num, x[0:1]) + squeeze(num, x[1:]) #i don't think this is right
```

I'm having trouble comparing the numbers in the list and putting it in the correct spot by using recursion.

Comment: What is the value of `v`?

Comment: Your `elif` is out of place

Comment: `x.append(num) x.sort() return x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
def squeeze(myList, num):
    if myList == []:
        return [num]
    elif num > myList[0]:
        return [myList[0]] + squeeze(myList[1:], num)
    else:
        return [num] + myList

print squeeze([1,4,7,9], 10)
print squeeze([1,4,7,9], 8)
print squeeze([1,4,7,9], 0)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4, 7, 9, 10]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 4, 7, 9]
```

**Explanation**

1. If `myList` is empty, return the `num` as list
2. If the `num` is greater than the first element of the `myList`, `num` cannot fit here. So, we recurse further leaving the first element of the `myList` behind. (`myList[1:]` means that without 0th element). For example, `myList` is `[4, 7, 9]` and `num` is 8. So, we leave 4 behind and recurse with `[7, 9]` and 8, still 8 is greater than 7, so now we recurse with `[9]` this time, 8 is smaller than 9, so we return `[8, 9]` by the else part. And when the recursion unwinds, we get `[7, 8, 9]` and then finally `[4, 7, 8, 9]`
3. If the `num` is lesser than or equal to first element of `myList`, then that is where we need to place `num`. So, we simply place `num` at the beginning of `myList` and return it.

Comment: Can you explain what you did in the 4th - 7th line? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Lalala I added little explanation please check that

Answer (score 0):

OK, there is already an answer upvoted and accepted BUT on the chance that this is not just a leaning/homework thing and someone actually wants to do this, **there's a module for this**.

check out what's available in [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html).

```
from bisect import insort

a = [1,4,7,9]
insort(a, 10)
print a

a = [1,4,7,9]
insort(a, 8)
print a

a = [1,4,7,9]
insort(a, 0)
print a
```

output is what is expected but there is also `insort_left` and `insort_right` to fine-tune your policy on ties.

**Note:** this does not return a *new* list, it modifies the old but is easily wrapped with a copy of the original first leaving you with a two line `squeeze` function.